LVP on top of bathroom tile
We have this bathroom tile that has lots of grooves. Would we be able to put LVP on top of it, or will we feel all the various textures / grooves of the tile underneath?  If LVP on top is not a good idea, is there another way to cheaply & DIY-friendly 'modernize' this a bit?


Would need to be very thin LVP to feel them.  The main problem with floors are they are not flat enough.  Use along straight edge in both directions.  If the straight edge lays flat with no dips/bumps beside the small grooves, you are good to go.

The "right" way would be to remove the old tile or put something over the floor to fill the grooves. That could be a liquid or a sheet, but I would avoid wood in a bathroom due to potential problems with moisture.
With a thin vinyl, any grooves or bumps will definitely telegraph through the floor.
For the relatively low-traffic area of a bathroom, Using a thicker LVP/LVT, you might get away with it. If you've never gone shopping for LVP, take a trip to the home center and see what the difference between the $0.89/sq and $5/sq products are.
This is a very small area so I think I would try it using a thicker plank with an attached backing: the worst that could happen is a few years from now you are unhappy with the result and you would have to take it out and try again, which would be a very modest cost for the materials.

Thank you - what do I do on the edge (where the LVP would meet the bathtub)? Do I caulk?

Caulk is what I would do for waterproofing and because I would not want to have any kind of quarter-round or baseboard next to my tub. Cut carefully and install with less than the usual 1/4" expansion gap at the edges. You might want a transition piece at the door. If it were me, I would also pull the toilet and reinstall it over the top of the new floor, because I am not smart enough to make running the floor up to the toilet base look good.

Makes sense, thank you!

Choose an LVP with a total thickness of 6MM or thicker with a solid core and you will be fine. Don't try to save money using thin products.
I have installed LVP over tile, wood, concrete and vinyl floors. If the floor underneath is in good shape and bonded well to the subfloor you are good to go.
If more reassurance is needed, you can spread a thin coat of thin set tile mortar over the grout lines and groves. Use the flat side of a tile trowel or a hard grout float.  When dry sweep up anything loose.  Remember you're not coating the entire floor, just filling in the groves.
If you are especially anal about flatness, cover the floor with leveling compound. However in your case I think this is an unnecessary expense and waste of time.
